# how to call a particular method or service at a specific time on daily in java spring

Tags: java, spring

```
public class ReminderBeep {
    Toolkit toolkit;

    Timer timer;

    public ReminderBeep(int seconds) {
        toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            toolkit.beep();
            System.out.println("Time's up!");

            // timer.cancel(); //Not necessary because we call System.exit

            // Stops the AWT thread (and everything else)
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("About to schedule task.");
        new ReminderBeep(5);
**strong text**
        System.out.println("Task scheduled.");
    }
}
```

how to automatic call method or service in spring

Comment: you can schedule a task http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: Always method should be call at a particular time

Comment: Yes, you can do that via giving a proper cron expression with the task
eg. scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("* 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways to do this.

1) [Using Quartz Scheduler Framework](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/)
2) [Using annotation type scheduled](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.RC2/javadoc-api//org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html)
Click on the link,you will get detailed information with example

Comment: Always method should be call at a particular time

Comment: Refer this you will get complete idea http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use @Schedule.

Look at the documentation here : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: Always method should be call at a particular time

Answer (score 0):

Spring Framework provides Scheduler which is used to achieve the objective:

Using `@Scheduled` annotation: [Link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled)

Answer (score 0):

This has some useful example [Spring Guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Comment: Always method should be call at a particular time